# ODI Mapping Generates Invalid XML with Duplicate Ending Tags

Tags: tags, double

We are facing an issue while writing data into XML file its ending up adding extra ending tags for one tag.

Its happening intermittently Sometimes Double ending tags not coming and and in some runs ending tags are coming .
I have gone through Doc ID 2752882.1 and we have done some code changes and regenerated scenario and deployed but still issue persists.

Below is XML looks like below.

Can someone please suggest on this
we have tried regenerating scenario after some code changes and deployed to prod ..Thought it will solve the problem But still it  persists.

Comment: Below is the Sample XML which is being created
<PromotionTypeName>CategoryLevelPerItemValueDiscount</PromotionTypeName>
   <PromotionCodeRequired>0</PromotionCodeRequired>
   <PromotionCodeCue></PromotionCodeCue></PromotionCodeCue>
   <DisplayLevel>0</DisplayLevel>

Comment: Can someone Please help on it